# Pandas Profiling doesn't display the output

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

Good Morning,

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df)

                  Company              ...      Sales
0                  Medi ltd.           ...      4.16000
1                  Pia  ltd.           ...      2.59907

[26958 rows x 15 columns]
```

But whenever I run:

```
import pandas_profiling as pp
pp.ProfileReport(df)
```

It just outputs, withouth plots or frames:

```
Out[92]: <pandas_profiling.ProfileReport at 0x1131e0668>
```

I tried generating a sample df, but it doesn't work either:

```
print(sample)

     Col1 Col2
Row1    1    2
Row2    3    4
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What does it show if you do `pp.ProfileReport(df).to_html()`?

Comment: '<!doctype html>\n\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n\n  <title>Profile report</title>\n  <meta name="description" content="Profile report generated by pandas-profiling. See GitHub.">\n  <meta name="author" content="pandas-profiling">\n    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>\n\n  (...)

Comment: And if you do `from IPython.core.display import display, HTML;display(HTML(pp.ProfileReport(df).to_html()))`

Comment: This is the output: <IPython.core.display.HTML object>

Comment: Looks like a problem with Jupyter

Comment: I am using Spyder from Anaconda, could it be related to that? In Jupyter it works perfectly.

Comment: If Spyder uses IPython then it does not know what to do with that html output.

Comment: Okay, this is the reason then! There is no way to display it there?

Comment: I could only find the solution I posted above, but it does not work, so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer for future reference:

- This is not a `pandas-profiling` specific issue. Spyder does seem to have issues with displaying HTML, more information can be found in this disscussion:
  https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4582
- A quick workaround would be to save the report to a file. You can do that like this:

```
report = pp.ProfileReport(df)
report.to_file('profile_report.html')
```

Comment: I'm running this in a conda environment in vs code and I don't get any output, error or otherwise, with trying any of this. Any thoughts why this may be occuring? I can open a new question if needed